# In Mongodb, should i use two indexes (with one a subset of the other) or a single one to have the best performance?

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, indexing

Let's say I have a mongodb database with a collection of milions of documents. I have a python script that tries to fetch those documents, because of the input of the user, sometimes i have to filter the documents using:

```
field1
field2
field3
```

document fields, other times i only need field1, field2 and others only field1.

Should I create 3 indexes, one containing compound all the three fields, one with the subset of field1 and field2 and a third with only field1, or is it better to have only the first one?

I tried doing some experiments but i'm having quite inconsistent results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index created on {field1, field2, field3} (IN that order) can be used for three types of queries:

```
db.doc.find( field1= 'a val' ,field2='a val', field3='a val')  
db.doc.find( field1= 'a val' ,field2='a val') 
db.doc.find( field1= 'a val')
```

But it can NOT be used for the following:

```
db.doc.find( field2= 'a val')
```

So if you going query for exactly they way you mentioned => Create only one Index in that order.

If you going to query in different orders => you will need multiple indexes

Comment: Raghu thanks for the answer. Do you know the why of this behaviour?

Comment: MongoDB (and most of databases) uses B-Tree for index structure, reading up how B-Trees help searching would better answer your question.